# Function to iterate through a pd.DataFrame and return a list not working properly, returns only an empty string

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create a function that would go through rows in a column called `df['loan status']`, and assign values 1 or 0 to list `loan_repaid` based on whether `loan_status` is "Fully Paid" or "Charged Off". The column always only contains one of the two.

```
loan_repaid = [] 

def get_binary():
    for x in df['loan_status']:
        if "FUlly Paid" in df['loan_status']:
            loan_repaid.append(1)
        if 'Charged Off' in df['loan_status']:
            loan_repaid.append(0)
        else: 
            pass
```

Unfortunately my attempt does nothing, and just returns an empty list :).

I peaked at the solution in the course that I am following and it goes with a more elegant solution:

```
df['loan_repaid'] = df['loan_status'].map({'Fully Paid':1,'Charged Off':0})
```

Which makes perfect sense, but I'd still like to know why my function isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```py
if "Fully Paid" in df['loan_status']:
```

The right hand side evaluates to a `pd.Series`. For a series, the `in` operator was defined to check if a **label** exists:

```py
"Fully Paid" in df["loan_status"] # False, no row with label/index "Fully Paid"
0 in df["loan_status"]            # True, there is a label/index 0
```

You already found a more elegant solution. But if you were to use a loop, change it to:

```py
def get_binary():
    for x in df['loan_status']:
        if "Fully Paid" in x:
            loan_repaid.append(1)
        if 'Charged Off' in x:
            loan_repaid.append(0)
        else: 
            pass
```